Uploading video from React Native to FastAPI causing "Axios Network Error: Unrecognized FormData part"
I'm trying to upload a video from my React Native app to my FastAPI server but I keep Axios Network Error: Unrecognized FormData part.
Frontend:
const uploadSelectedVideo = async ({
    selectedVideo,
  }: {
    selectedVideo: ImagePicker.ImagePickerAsset;
  }) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    try {
      const response = await fetch(selectedVideo.uri);
      const videoBlob = await response.blob();
      
      // Append the video Blob to FormData
      formData.append("file", videoBlob, "video.mp4");
      const uploadResponse = await uploadVideo({ payload: formData });
      console.log("Video uploaded successfully:", uploadResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error uploading video: ${error}`);
    }
  };

export const uploadVideo = async ({ payload }: { payload: FormData }) => {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${ENV_VARS?.API_URL}/api/video/upload`,
    payload,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    }
  );
  // Log the response status and data
  console.log("Response status:", response.status);
  console.log("Response data:", response.data);

  if (!response.data) {
    throw new Error("No response data provided");
  }
  return response.data;
};

Backend:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from app.routes import video_routes

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(video_routes.router)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@router.post("/api/video/upload")
async def upload_video_route(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        return await upload_video(file)
    except HTTPException as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Error with file received")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Unexpected error in upload_video_route: {str(e)}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="An unexpected error occurred")

This is what the frontend also holds within formData:
{"_parts": [["file", [Blob]]]}
What I've tried so far:

Testing via Postman and the Swagger docs. Both are working.
Tried removing headers. Still not working.
Tried calling other endpoints. I can verify my root endpoint is working on React Native.
Testing on Android and I'm already using 10.0.2.2


Does this answer your question?

Related answers might also be found here and here

Instead of blob try passing this in form data:
formData.append('file', {
          uri: selectedVideo.uri,
          type: selectedVideo.type,
          name: selectedVideo.fileName,
        });


This worked thanks! However, I needed to mark it with @ts-ignore to ensure typescript doesn't complain about it.
